# TSQL strip date from datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql

What is the best way to strip the *date* from a DATETIME so only *time* is left to do a comparison?

I know I can do the following:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),8))
```

But this involves convert and characters. If I wanted to check whether a time (including minutes) was between two other times stored in DATETIME columns, is there an elegant way to do this without having to rely on converting to character strings?

Comment: a `DATETIME` value will always have a date element (clue's in the name :) so the only way of literally removing the date "so only time is left" is to cast it as a type that has no date element i.e. @Mike M.'s answer.

Comment: I should have specified that our software uses SQL2005 (and was designed in the era of SQL2000 so the TIME datatype, which is a new feature of SQL2008 is not a feasible solution. If you look at the answer which was marked correct, you'll see an elegant solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the TimeOnly function from [Essential SQL Server Date, Time, and DateTime Functions](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx):

```
create function TimeOnly(@DateTime DateTime)
returns datetime
as
    begin
    return dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @datetime), @datetime)
    end
go
```

Or simply cast the DateTime as Time in SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @time as time
set @time = cast(dateTimeVal as time)
```

Comment: Your 2 solutions produce different results:

The first, with use of a function returns a 'datetime' object as required, but the date component is set to '1900-01-01'. One could argue about what 'stripped' actually means but this will work as required.

The second, with the cast, returns a 'time' datatype which has no date.

Arguably, the cast is thus not quite right as the question implies that a datetime should be returned

Answer (score 14):

If you're using SQL 2008

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE 
  @Now DateTime, 
  @Today DateTime,
  @Time DateTime

SET @Now = GetDate() 
SET @Today = DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, @Now), 0) 

SET @Time = DateAdd(ss, DateDiff(ss, @Today, @Now), 0)

SELECT @Time
```

Comment: Beautiful. Absolutely beautiful. in an MSDE DB, I used the @Today calculation to strip the time from a passed date, works splendidly.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to get date and time from datetime.

datetime in SQL Server implemented as float value where whole part **floor(value)** is day from 1900-01-01 and fractional part **(value - floor(value))** is part of twenty-four hours elapsed from start of day

```
select 
    d as [datetime],
    cast(cast(T.d as float) - floor(cast(T.d as float)) as datetime) as [time],
    cast(floor(cast(T.d as float)) as datetime) as [date]
from
    (values
        (getdate()),
        ('1753-01-01 23:59:59.700'),
        ('1899-12-31 00:00:00.300'),
        ('1900-01-01 00:00:00.300')
    ) as T(d);
```