# Date only in sql

Tags: date, sql-server-2005-express

My data is like below

> 2010-11-09 13:20:02.000

I'd like to get date only. Which sql function will i use?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 (or newer) has a `DATE` datatype for this exact purpose...

Comment: Possible dublicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283039/tsql-strip-date-from-datetime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124808/need-only-date-from-datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference (because of its flexibility) is `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,'2010-11-09T13:20:02.000'),0)
```

It's flexible, because you can use the same pattern to achieve other rounding effects. E.g. to get the first of the month, you can dateadd/datediff month rather than day. It can also be used to find, e.g. the end of the month for the given date, or the end of the month, 3 months from the given date.